# Run R Shiny app as HTTPS in Docker container

Tags: docker, shiny, https

I have a Shiny app running in Docker container at http://subdomain.mydomain.com:3838. To start this app I call usual "docker run -dt -p 3838:3838 my_app_docker_image".

However I need to run this app as https://subdomain.mydomain.com:3838 and I am not able to get it working. Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Note: Docker is running on dedicated sever, nothing else except Docker and this app is not there. As a part of my attempts to make it working I installed Apache2 and SSL certificate, so I am able to successfully display https://subdomain.mydomain.com.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run shinyapp in https mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61618036/run-shinyapp-in-https-mode)

Comment: hi @smartse, thanks fir response.
I have already seen the original guide that post is reffering to; as I understood, it is a guide to run Shiny with SSL when  Shiny is installed on the server. However I run my Shiny app in Docker, I do not have installed Shiny on my server. So I am afraid this does not solve my issue..but thanks once again